# how to protect xen server free when accessed through browser?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualization, xen

we are having **xen server free** running on a  remote machine,which is having a public ip,through which i am access the console...

When accessed through browser its showing a page to download xen centre.

i want that to be hidden,i tried iptables to block it by disabling port 80 from other ips.But after that i could nt access the xen server using Xen Centre.Is there a better way to solve this?

Update:

that was  iptable miss configuration allowing 127.0.0.1 to connect solved this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use iptables to block port 80 from all ips apart from yours? That would still enable you to use the console etc.

Comment: yes that was what i did.. it fixed browser problem but after that citrix xen centre lost its connection.

Comment: Sounds like you got the iptables rule wrong- as this shouldn't have affected your connection. Xen Server is designed to use a console card on a seperate ip, rather than on a public ip for management

Comment: i setted this on a local machine and gave this rule
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp ! -s my-ip --dport 80 -j REJECT
but after this xen centre couldnt connect

Comment: ohh...it was iptable miss configuration..
 allowing localhost to connect fixed that...sorry....

Answer (score 0):

That was iptable misconfiguration. Allowing 127.0.0.1 to connect solved this.

```
iptables -I INPUT ! -s allowed-ip --dport 80 -j REJECT
iptables -I INPUT 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
```